# CASE statement with search in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have used CASE statement for action column.Is it possible to search with value **view**

How to add **WHERE** condition with **LIKE** operator for action column

```
SELECT al.id,
       al.article_file_id,
       U.firstname,
       U.lastname,
       al.action,
       al.accessed_time,
       a.file_size,
       al.is_backup,
       a.display_file_name,
       fb.display_file_name,
       CASE
           WHEN al.action ='v' THEN 'view'
           WHEN al.action = 'd' THEN 'download'
       END AS actions
FROM rfal al
LEFT JOIN `ru` U ON al.user_id = U.id
LEFT JOIN raf a ON a.id = al.article_file_id
LEFT JOIN rafb fb ON fb.list_id = al.article_file_id
WHERE (a.display_file_name LIKE "%s%")||(a.file_size LIKE "%s%")||(al.id LIKE "%s%")
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 0,10;
```

My Problem is

In db , the value of action column is saved as v but i am displaying in the table as View . I have put a search filter for table and when i enter v ,it will give the result but typing **view** no results found is showing.
Input data is shown below

[image]

Comment: What is the actual problem/question?

Comment: In db , the value of action column is saved as v but i am displaying in the    table as View . I have put a search filter for table and when i enter v ,it will give the result but typing view no results found is showing.

Comment: Can we use alias as filter ?

Comment: No, not in the `WHERE` clause, but we can use an alias in the `HAVING` clause, or we can subquery.

Comment: So for getting above output , what can i do ?

Comment: This is an incomplete question, and I predict you will either not get an answer, or get only bad answers.  Please show us sample input data, the expected output, and then what query you have tried.